# Adding a new .NET SDK to Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, amazon-web-services

I am relatively new to Visual Studio and .NET and VB.NET. I recently installed the Amazon Web Services .NET SDK and I am trying to figure out how to get things running, specifically do I need to do anything to include the SDK in an existing project? I know there is some sample code, but its in C# and the project is already set up so I don't find it very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a VB expert but you should be able to include the AWS dll to your existing project. That way you can use AWS API functions.
You can locate the dll using the sample project. (As I remember the name of the dll is AWS2SDK.dll or something like that..)

Comment: Thanks, but, I found AWSSDK.dll and added to my project. When I look at the sample code in C# I see the following lines: using Amazon; using Amazon.S3; using Amazon.S3.Model; I am assuming (perhaps wrongly) that 'using' in C# is the same as 'Import' in VB. 'Import Amazon' works, 'Import Amazon S3' generates an error.

Comment: Ah, got it, I had to do 'Imports System.net'. Thanks.